# Making Disqus 2012 RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, disqus

AS you know Disqus 2012 loads in an iframe and no longer we are able to customize it! it is not a very big deal for LTR languages such as English but for Persian and Arabic it is very big deal. is it possible to style Disqus and replace some strings at client-side using javascript?
I have searched on the internet but there was no solution to Disqus 2012 because it loads in an iframe.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can access iframe's content using javascript. You can watch a tutorial in [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-inject-custom-html-and-css-into-an-iframe/). But I'm not sure if this approach works for Disqus.

**Edit:** here's a similar question: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe), try the best answer.
**Edit 2:** It does NOT work cross-domain.